# swiftUI : How I can use H or VStack container with List in NavigationView

Tags: list, swiftui, stack

```
    import SwiftUI

struct FolderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Text("hi")
                }
                .frame(height : 50)
                .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
                .background(.blue)
            
                
                List {
                    Text("hi")
                }
            }
            
            .navigationTitle("Task Folders ")
        }
    }
}

struct FolderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FolderView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Hi! I tried to use Hstack container in NavigationView with List, But as you can see in my attached screenshot, it is working like that, I mean the container is mixed with navigationView Area.

Is there a some way that I can solve? How I can use that with List?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fixed variant - use as a background not a color but filled rectangle. Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image: demo]

```
    HStack{
        Text("hi")
    }
    .frame(height : 50)
    .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
    .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.blue))    // << here !!
```

*Note: it is not clear for now whether that is a bug or a new NavigationView+background(color) feature.*

Comment: Asperi, Thank you so much!! I will try that right now! big help!!